# Program using shared library and sf::Window not entering main function

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, sfml

I added some layers to the SFML library.
I wanted to make it a shared library that others programs should use. Problem is, when I try to use a function inside this library, the main function is not called, but the program is still running.

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << "entry" << std::endl;
  // Calling a function inside my library
  FunctionInsideLibrary();
  return (0);
}
```

What I know :

- If I link my library but don't call any function from my
  library the program will show entry
- Consequently, if I use a function, entry does not show but the program is running (need to Ctrl-C to close it)
- If I create a static library it does not happen
- I tried to link with
  others libraries and it works fine (the problem must be related to
  SFML)
- I just tried to link with a dummy library that use a sf::Window. Apparently it's the class responsible for my problem (others SFML class works).

Edit: 
Apparently it's because I used a "global" variable SFML Window (in a anonymous namespace). Using a pointer or inside a class do the trick. I would like to know why it's not possible though.

Comment: Tried stepping through it with gdb?

Comment: I did try to put a breakpoint to my main but it does not enter it. And a breakpoint to the Entry point say that it's in a shared library, and still do nothing. It is because I use my window as a global variable. But why...

Comment: There isn't enough information to really help. What's the code of your library? How did you link SFML? How do you link against the libraries? And yes you should not use global variables, especially with SFML, since unfortunately SFML makes use of global variables.

Comment: Didn't you read my post ? It's an anonymous namespace, completely different. And to reproduce the bug you just have to put a global variable sf::Window into a shared library and link it. That's it.

Comment: It's encouraged to answer your own question instead of editing your question. If you have another question regarding the answer you found, you should post a new question.

Comment: I understand. But it's just a patch not an answer. I still don't understand why it does not work when I use a global variable.